# Camera doesn't follow curve smoothly

Tags: camera, bezier-curves

I have set the camera to follow the path of a Bezier Curve. However the camera seems to only touch between the handles themselves instead of following the true path of the curve.

Comment: could you please share your file (at least camera + curve)?

Comment: I wish I could but my file size is 125mb which exceeds the 30mb limit. Thats with blender-exchange, let me know if you know any other way.

Comment: try this one: http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That also has a 30mb upload limit

Comment: @moonboots please keep in mind that links in pasteall.org expire. Once the link is gone other users cannot access it and learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, the curve resolution was too low, so even though the preview looked like a curve the actual resolution wasn't smooth. I just upped the resolution U and it worked perfectly.